# How can I avoid repeated inserts in Java Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

How can I avoid the repeated test when I need to test the insert of a child entity in a **Integration Test**????

Use case:

I have a Person entity (parent) and a Phone entity (child). I need to persist a Phone before persist a Person but if I have a entity with a lot of child, my test will be a monster of duplicated code!!!!

I need something like:

```
public class TestPerson {

    public void should_insertPerson_and_find(){
        //I need to call should_insertPhone_and_find() to insert a Phone before insert people, because of dependency.....
        //... run test
    }

}

public class TestPhone {

    public void should_insertPhone_and_find(){
        //... run test
    }

}
```

Can someone sugest any API for this? Can JUnit do this?

Comment: If all you want to test is to make sure the child entity is inserted properly, then why can't you do that with single entity? why you need multiple child entities to verify?

Comment: Because I'm running an integration test and I need to test the relationship between entities

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way I found it is the [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-7-dependency-test/) dependency test article!!!!

Thanks for the answers guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the options are:

- Have a common abstract superclass with a `@Before` method that does the initialization
- Use [JUnit Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules)
- Create a Utility method in another class and call the method from `@Before` methods in both classes

Comment: More comment, than answer

Comment: @hd1 if you think so, flag it as "should be a comment". Let's see if the mods agree

Answer (score 1):

Any test should stay easy to read.
Here is what I suggest.

```
// given
cleanTestPersonsAndPhones();
Phone tphone = createTestPhone ("testShouldA");
Person tperson = createTestPerson(tphone);

// when
// should find tphone or tperson relation(s)

// then
// verify find result (s)
 cleanTestPersonsAndPhones();
```

I m not fan of using @before and filtering by method name because test is less easy to re-read...